# How to extract text from small image using Python openCV

Tags: python-2.7, opencv

I'm New for python openCV,can you help me to extract text from small image ,i have tried may online tutorial.But i'm not getting exact output.

My Image.

[image]

My Code

```
import sys
import cv2 as cv
import numpy as np
import pytesseract
from pytesseract import image_to_string
 img = Image.open('SampleImage.PNG')
 img = im.filter(ImageFilter.SHARPEN())
 enhancer = ImageEnhance.Contrast(img)
 img.save("Cleaned1.PNG",quality=100)
 img.show()
 pytesseract.pytesseract.tesseract_cmd = 'F:\\Tesseract-OCR\\tesseract'
 print("OCR Output : " + pytesseract.image_to_string(img))
```

Comment: Many ways to use this. Post code you tried. Edge detection in openCV is a good thing to look at first.

Comment: @BenjaminHorn,Thanks for your response please check my edited post.

Comment: @BenjaminHorn,Any update.